# AZURE_QUOTA_EXCEEDED_EXCEPTION , How to solve this?

Tags: azure-databricks

[Quota Exceeded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE8mW.png)

When trying to start warehouse in azure databricks sql analytics, the error while importing data to dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quotas/networking-quota-requests) on increasing corresponding quota for Azure.

But really, you need to deploy a new workspace that won't require public IPs for cluster nodes - so called secure cluster connectivity, or No Public IP ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secure-cluster-connectivity)). Unfortunately right now you can't change this setting for existing workspace.